# Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?

Tags: scripting, executable, shebang

This may be a silly question, but I ask it still. If I have declared a shebang

```
#!/bin/bash
```

in the beginning of `my_shell_script.sh`, so do I always have to invoke this script using bash

```
[my@comp]$bash my_shell_script.sh
```

or can I use e.g.

```
[my@comp]$sh my_shell_script.sh
```

and my script determines the running shell using the shebang? Is it the same happening with `ksh` shell? I'm using AIX.

Comment: there is a little confusion on your part: when you do "_some_shell  some_script" it starts _some_shell and asks it to interpret some_script. So no, if you do "sh my_shell_script.sh" it won't interpret the shebang, but will interpret the script in sh instead. To use the shebang :   `chmod +x my_shell_script.sh ;   /path/to/my_shell_script.sh  # or  ./my_shell_script.sh if you happen to be in its directory`

Answer (score 147, accepted):

The *shebang* `#!` is an human readable instance of a [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) consisting of the byte string `0x23 0x21`, which is used by the `exec()` family of functions to determine whether the file to be executed is a script or a binary. When the shebang is present, `exec()` will run the executable specified after the shebang instead.

Note that this means that if you invoke a script by specifying the interpreter on the command line, as is done in **both** cases given in the question, `exec()` will execute the interpreter specified on the command line, it won't even look at the script.

So, as others have noted, if you want `exec()` to invoke the interpreter specified on the shebang line, the script must have the executable bit set and invoked as `./my_shell_script.sh`.

The behaviour is easy to demonstrate with the following script:

```
#!/bin/ksh
readlink /proc/$$/exe
```

**Explanation:**

- `#!/bin/ksh` defines `ksh` to be the interpreter.
- `$$` holds the PID of the current process.
- `/proc/pid/exe` is a symlink to the executable of the process (at least on Linux; on AIX, /proc/$$/object/a.out is a link to the executable).
- `readlink` will output the value of the symbolic link.

**Example:**

**Note**: I'm demonstrating this on Ubuntu, where the default shell `/bin/sh` is a symlink to **dash** i.e. `/bin/dash` and `/bin/ksh` is a symlink to `/etc/alternatives/ksh`, which in turn is a symlink to `/bin/pdksh`.

```
$ chmod +x getshell.sh
$ ./getshell.sh 
/bin/pdksh
$ bash getshell.sh 
/bin/bash
$ sh getshell.sh 
/bin/dash
```

Comment: thanks Thomas for this answer. Pretend we launch the script as a child process from Node.js or Java or whatever. Can we launch an "exec" process, and then exec will run the shell script? I ask beause I am looking for answers to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41067872/differentiate-between-bash-and-sh-via-node-js-child-process/41068232#41068232

Comment: @AlexanderMills The [`exec()`](https://linux.die.net/man/3/exec) referred to in this answer is a system call, the command [`exec`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/exec) is a shell builtin, which is why you cannot invoke an `exec` _program_ from Node.js or Java. However, any shell command invoked by e.g. `Runtime.exec()` in Java is eventually processed by the `exec()` system call.

Comment: Huh, yeah I am indeede familiar with the Java API you just mentioned, I wonder if there is a way to invoke the lower level exec() call from Node.js somehow

Comment: @AlexanderMills I would imagine `child_process.{exec(),execFile(),spawn()`} all would be implemented using the C `exec()` (through [`process`](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/63243bcb330408d511b3945c53719425d8b7abb8/deps/uv/src/unix/process.c)).

Comment: Node.js is a *Javascript* program, not a *Java* program, so any similarities between the behavior of Node.js and the Java API are purely coincidental.

Comment: "*Note that if you invoke a script by specifying the interpreter on the command line, as is done in both cases given in the question, `exec()` will execute the interpreter specified on the command line, **it won't even look at the script**.*" This explains why running `./myscript.sh` results in a process named "myscript.sh" whereas running `bash myscript.sh` (or having `#! /usr/bin/env bash` in the shebang line) results in a "bash" process. Thanks!

Comment: _... the script must have the executable bit set and invoked as ./my_shell_script.sh._ As @Olivier Dulac noted in the comment, this is valid only when the script is in the current directory. Otherwise something like `/path/to/the/script/my_shell_script.sh` or `../../other/dir/my_shell_script.sh` must be used. And if the script is in the directory listed in the `PATH`, then just `my_shell_script.sh` will suffice.

Answer (score 10):

Yes it does. By the way it is not a silly question. A reference for my answer is [here](http://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/Shebang#Starting_a_Script_With_.23.21).
 Starting a Script With #!

- It is called a shebang or a "bang" line.
- It is nothing but the absolute path to the Bash interpreter.
- It consists of a number sign and an exclamation point character (#!), followed by the
  full path to the interpreter such as /bin/bash.

  All scripts under Linux execute using the interpreter specified on a first line
  Almost all bash scripts often begin with #!/bin/bash (assuming that Bash has been installed in /bin)
  This ensures that Bash will be used to interpret the script, even if it is executed under another shell.
  The shebang was introduced by Dennis Ritchie between Version 7 Unix and 8 at Bell Laboratories. It was then also added to the BSD line at Berkeley .

Ignoring An Interpreter Line (shebang)

If you do not specify an interpreter line, the default is usually the /bin/sh. But, it is recommended that you set #!/bin/bash line.

Comment: To elaborate, the kernel only knows how to execute statically linked binaries and where to find interpreter information for others (a special field in the binary, or the shebang line). Typically executing a shell script means following the shebang line to the shell, and then following the DT_INTERP field in the shell binary to the dynamic linker.

Comment: Also note that this isn't limited to shell scripts. All text based script files use this. eg `#!/usr/bin/perl` `#!/usr/local/bin/python` `#!/usr/local/bin/ruby` Another common shebang entry used to support multiple systems is to use env to locate the interpreter you want to use, like `#!/usr/bin/env perl` `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: @sambler speaking of `env`, which should be actually prefered? Python and Perl often use `env`, while on shellscripts, this is often omitted and shebang points to the shell in question.

Comment: @polemon less of which is preferred and more on which paths vary. The basic shells are in the same path on all systems. Up to date versions of perl and python can be installed in different locations on different systems so using env allows the same shebang to always work, which is why env is used more with perl and python scripts than shell scripts.

Comment: `env` to find a program in $PATH is a bit of a hack.  It doesn't set environment variables like the name implies. $PATH might be a different result for different users. But it helps scripts run without modification on systems which put a reasonable perl interpreter in some odd place.

Comment: The cited source, and consequently this answer, contains a number of errors: The **executable** specified after the shebang is the interpreter for the rest of the script, and is frequently *not* bash. As @thomas-nyman points out, the shebang-specified interpreter will be ignored if another shell is called on the command line to interpret the file. If `env` is used to specify the executable, the user's path is searched to find the program, it is not an absolute path. The default shell is operating system dependent, you cannot assume it will be `sh`.

Comment: @JohnMahowald [env(1)](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/env.html) sets the environment variables, but it will execute the script itself again, creating an endless loop. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/670339/367454

Answer (score 6):

**The `exec` system call of the Linux kernel understands shebangs (`#!`) natively**

I hadn't noticed that OP asked about AIX, I'm going to say what I know about Linux, and bet that there are strong analogies, or at least satisfy the majority of Googlers who are looking for Linux :-)

When you do on bash:

```
./something
```

on Linux, this calls the `exec` system call with the path `./something`.

This line of the kernel gets called on the file passed to `exec`: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.8/fs/binfmt_script.c#L25

```
if ((bprm->buf[0] != '#') || (bprm->buf[1] != '!'))
```

It reads the very first bytes of the file, and compares them to `#!`.

If the comparison is true, then the rest of the line is parsed by the Linux kernel, which makes another `exec` call with path `/usr/bin/env python` and current file as the first argument:

```
/usr/bin/env python /path/to/script.py
```

and this works for any scripting language that uses `#` as a comment character.

And yes, you can make an infinite loop with:

```
printf '#!/a\n' | sudo tee /a
sudo chmod +x /a
/a
```

Bash recognizes the error:

```
-bash: /a: /a: bad interpreter: Too many levels of symbolic links
```

`#!` just happens to be human readable, but that is not required.

If the file started with different bytes, then the `exec` system call would use a different handler. The other most important built-in handler is for ELF executable files: https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/v4.8/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L1305 which checks for bytes `7f 45 4c 46` (which also happens to be human readable for `.ELF`). Let's confirm that by reading the 4 first bytes of `/bin/ls`, which is an ELF executable:

```
head -c 4 "$(which ls)" | hd
```

output:

```
00000000  7f 45 4c 46                                       |.ELF|
00000004
```

So when the kernel sees those bytes, it takes the ELF file, puts it into memory correctly, and starts a new process with it. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8352535/how-does-kernel-get-an-executable-binary-file-running-under-linux/31394861#31394861

Finally, you can add your own shebang handlers with the `binfmt_misc` mechanism. For example, you can add a [custom handler for `.jar` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1667830/running-a-jar-file-without-directly-calling-java). This mechanism even supports handlers by file extension. Another application is to [transparently run executables of a different architecture with QEMU](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41889/how-can-i-chroot-into-a-filesystem-with-a-different-architechture).

I don't think POSIX specifies shebangs, however: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/346214/32558, although it does mention it in rationale sections, and in the form "if executable scripts are supported by the system something may happen".

Comment: Running `./something` from a shell won't pass the *full* path to `exec`, but exactly the path entered. Can you correct this in your answer? Do `echo "$0"` in your script and you will see this is the case.

Comment: This answer has missed the "I'm using AIX." in the question.

Comment: @JdeBP so does every Googler who comes to the question :-)

Answer (score 5):

In fact, if you take it consequently, the executable noted in the shebang line, is just an executable. It makes sense to use some text interpreter as executable, but it is not necessary. Just for clarification and demonstration, i made a rather useless test:

```
#!/bin/cat
useless text
more useless text
still more useless text
```

Named the file test.txt and set the exectuable bit `chmod u+x test.txt`, then "called" it: `./test.txt`. As expected, the contents of the file is output. In this case, cat does not ignore the shebang line. It simply outputs all lines. Any useful interpreter should thus be able to ignore this shebang line. For bash, perl and PHP, it is simply a comment line. So yes, these ignore the shebang line.

Answer (score -1):

From what I gathered, whenever a file has an executable bit set and is invoked, the kernel analyzes the file header in order to determine how to proceed (as far as I know, you can add custom handlers for custom file formats via LKMs). If the file appears to be a text file with a #! combination in the beginning, its execution is dispatched to another executable (usually a shell of sorts), a path to which is to be specified directly after the said shebang, in the same line. The kernel then proceeds to execute the shell and pass the file for it to handle.

In short, it doesn't matter which shell you invoke the script with - the kernel will dispatch the execution to the appropriate one either way.

Comment: There's a marked difference between `bash ./myscript.sh` and `./myscript.sh`.

Comment: What do you mean by this "marked difference"?

Comment: @jrara See my answer, the statement that "it doesn't matter which shell you invoke the script with" is simply not true.