# Run a binary owned by root without sudo

Tags: permissions, executable

I had a question on a job interview:

> How can you execute (run) the program with the user `user1` without `sudo` privileges and without access to the `root` account:
>
> ```
> $ whoami
> user1
> $ ls -l ~/binary_program
> -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 126160 Jan 17 18:57 /home/user1/binary_program
> ```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you have read permission:

```
$ cp ~/binary_program my_binary
$ chmod +x my_binary
$ ./my_binary
```

Of course this will not auto-magically grant you escalated privileges. You would still be executing that binary as a regular user.

Comment: @user2555595 I'm afraid you're wrong. Try removing the execute bit on a file _you own_ and executing it. Even root gets "permission denied" when executing a file without the execute bit set.

Comment: you are right, thank you for the information

Comment: @user2555595 That only [applies for scripts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/87600/43779), not binaries. More specifically only `bash` or POSIX shell scripts if `bash` is invoked as the interpreter.

Comment: Thank you for your information, people! Have a nice day!

Comment: @inivanoff1 Please don't forget to mark one of the answers "Accepted" so that people know this question is solved.

Answer (score 20):

You can use the Linux [dynamic linker/loader](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html) directly to run [ELF executables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Executable_and_Linkable_Format) for which you have read, but not execute rights:

```
$ /lib/ld-linux.so.* /home/user1/binary_program
```

When an ELF executable is executed ordinarily, the dynamic linker which is stored in the `.interp` section of the program code is used. Reasons for invoking the dynamic linker directly (outside job interviews) include passing it command-line options to modify its behaviour.

Note that the actual location of the dynamic linker may very depending on the environment, for instance in 64-bit Ubuntu the linker is at `/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`.