# What exactly happens when I execute a file in my shell?

Tags: shell, kernel, exec, shebang

So, I thought I had a good understanding of this, but just ran a test (in response to a conversation where I disagreed with someone) and found that my understanding is flawed...

**In as much detail as possible** what exactly happens when I execute a file in my shell? What I mean is, if I type: `./somefile some arguments` into my shell and press return (and `somefile` exists in the cwd, and I have read+execute permissions on `somefile`) then what happens under the hood?

I *thought* the answer was:

1. The shell make a syscall to `exec`, passing the path to `somefile`
2. The kernel examines `somefile` and looks at [the magic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)#Magic_numbers_in_files) of the file to determine if it is a format the processor can handle
3. If the magic number indicates that the file is in a format the processor can execute, then

   1. a new process is created (with an entry in the process table)
   2. `somefile` is read/mapped to memory. A stack is created and execution jumps to the entry point of the code of `somefile`, with `ARGV` initialized to an array of the parameters (a `char**`, `["some","arguments"]`)
4. If the magic number is a [shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) then `exec()` spawns a new process as above, but the executable used is the interpreter referenced by the shebang (e.g. `/bin/bash` or `/bin/perl`) and `somefile` is passed to `STDIN`
5. If the file doesn't have a valid magic number, then an error like "invalid file (bad magic number): Exec format error" occurs

However someone told me that if the file is plain text, then the shell tries to execute the commands (as if I had typed `bash somefile`). I didn't believe this, but I just tried it, and it was correct. So I clearly have some misconceptions about what actually happens here, and would like to understand the mechanics.

What exactly happens when I execute a file in my shell? (in as much detail is reasonable...)

Comment: There's no perfect substitute for looking at the [source code](ftp://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/bash/bash-2.05b.tar.gz) for a full depth of understanding.

Comment: @Wildcard that's what I am doing right now, actually :-) If I can, I will answer my own question

Comment: `source somefile` is very different from a new process being forked off by `./somefile`, though.

Comment: @thrig yes, I agree. But I didn't think that `./somefile` would cause bash to execute the commands in `somefile` if the file didn't have a magic number. I thought it would just display an error, and instead it appears to effectively `source somefile`

Comment: I'm wrong again, I can confirm that if `somefile` is a text file, then a new shell is spawned if I try to execute it. A file `echo $$` behaves differently if I execute vs source it.

Comment: A related more shebang specific question: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script

Answer (score 40, accepted):

The definitive answer to "how programs get run" on Linux is the pair of articles on [LWN.net](https://lwn.net) titled, surprisingly enough, [How programs get run](https://lwn.net/Articles/630727/) and [How programs get run: ELF binaries](https://lwn.net/Articles/631631/). The first article addresses scripts briefly. (Strictly speaking the definitive answer is in the source code, but these articles are easier to read and provide links to the source code.)

A little experimentation show that you pretty much got it right, and that the execution of a file containing a simple list of commands, without a shebang, needs to be handled by the shell. The [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) manpage contains source code for a test program, execve; we'll use that to see what happens without a shell. First, write a testscript, `testscr1`, containing

```
#!/bin/sh

pstree
```

and another one, `testscr2`, containing only

```
pstree
```

Make them both executable, and verify that they both run from a shell:

```
chmod u+x testscr[12]
./testscr1 | less
./testscr2 | less
```

Now try again, using `execve` (assuming you built it in the current directory):

```
./execve ./testscr1
./execve ./testscr2
```

`testscr1` still runs, but `testscr2` produces

```
execve: Exec format error
```

This shows that the shell handles `testscr2` differently. It doesn't process the script itself though, it still uses `/bin/sh` to do that; this can be verified by piping `testscr2` to `less`:

```
./testscr2 | less -ppstree
```

On my system, I get

```
    |-gnome-terminal--+-4*[zsh]
    |                 |-zsh-+-less
    |                 |     `-sh---pstree
```

As you can see, there's the shell I was using, `zsh`, which started `less`, and a second shell, plain `sh` (`dash` on my system), to run the script, which ran `pstree`. In `zsh` this is handled by `zexecve` in [`Src/exec.c`](https://sourceforge.net/p/zsh/code/ci/master/tree/Src/exec.c#l524): the shell uses `execve(2)` to try to run the command, and if that fails, it reads the file to see if it has a shebang, processing it accordingly (which the kernel will also have done), and if that fails it tries to run the file with `sh`, as long as it didn't read any zero byte from the file:

```
        for (t0 = 0; t0 != ct; t0++)
            if (!execvebuf[t0])
                break;
        if (t0 == ct) {
            argv[-1] = "sh";
            winch_unblock();
            execve("/bin/sh", argv - 1, newenvp);
        }
```

`bash` has the same behaviour, implemented in [`execute_cmd.c`](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c#n4845) with a helpful comment (as pointed out by [taliezin](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/102632/taliezin)):

> Execute a simple command that is hopefully defined in a disk file
>     somewhere.
>
> 1. `fork ()`
> 2. connect pipes
> 3. look up the command
> 4. do redirections
> 5. `execve ()`
> 6. If the `execve` failed, see if the file has executable mode set.
>      If so, and it isn't a directory, then execute its contents as
>      a shell script.

POSIX defines a set of functions, known as [the `exec(3)` functions](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html), which wrap `execve(2)` and provide this functionality too; see [muru](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/70524/muru)'s answer for details. On Linux at least these functions are implemented by the C library, not by the kernel.

Comment: This is fantastic and has the detail I was looking for, thank you!

Answer (score 13):

In part, this depends on the particular `exec` family function that's used. `execve`, as [Stephen Kitt](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/268777/70524) has shown in detail, only runs files in the correct binary format or scripts that begin with a proper shebang.

*However*, `execlp` and `execvp` go one step further: if the shebang wasn't correct, the file is executed with `/bin/sh` on Linux. From [`man 3 exec`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exec.3.html):

```
Special semantics for execlp() and execvp()
   The execlp(), execvp(), and execvpe() functions duplicate the actions
   of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified
   filename does not contain a slash (/) character.
   …

   If the header of a file isn't recognized (the attempted execve(2)
   failed with the error ENOEXEC), these functions will execute the
   shell (/bin/sh) with the path of the file as its first argument.  (If
   this attempt fails, no further searching is done.)
```

This is somewhat supported by [POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html) (emphasis mine):

> One potential source of confusion noted by the standard developers is
>   over how the contents of a process image file affect the behavior of
>   the exec family of functions. The following is a description of the
>   actions taken:
>
> 1. If the process image file is a valid executable (in a format that is executable and valid and having appropriate privileges) for this
>      system, then the system executes the file.
> 2. If the process image file has appropriate privileges and is in a format that is executable but not valid for this system (such as a
>      recognized binary for another architecture), then this is an error and
>      errno is set to [EINVAL] (see later RATIONALE on [EINVAL]).
> 3. If the process image file has appropriate privileges but is not otherwise recognized:
>
>    1. **If this is a call to execlp() or execvp(), then they invoke a command interpreter assuming that the process image file is a shell
>         script.**
>    2. If this is not a call to execlp() or execvp(), then an error occurs and errno is set to [ENOEXEC].

This doesn't specify how the command interpreter is obtained, so, but doesn't specify that an error has to be given. I guess, therefore, that the Linux devs allowed such files to be run with `/bin/sh` (or this was already a common practice and they just followed suit).

FWIW, the [FreeBSD manpage for `exec(3)`](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=exec&apropos=0&sektion=3&manpath=FreeBSD%2010.2-RELEASE&arch=default&format=html) also mentions similar behaviour:

```
 Some of these functions have special semantics.

 The functions execlp(), execvp(), and execvP() will duplicate the actions
 of the shell in searching for an executable file if the specified file
 name does not contain a slash ``/'' character. 
 …
 If the header of a file is not recognized (the attempted execve()
 returned ENOEXEC), these functions will execute the shell with the path
 of the file as its first argument.  (If this attempt fails, no further
 searching is done.)
```

---

AFAICT, however, no common shell uses `execlp` or `execvp` directly, presumably for finer control over the environment. They all implement the same logic using `execve`.

Comment: I'd also add that at least on Linux, `execl`, `execlp`, `execle`, `execv`, `execvp` and `execvpe` are all front-ends to the `execve` syscall; the former are provided by the C library, the kernel only knows about `execve` (and `execveat` nowadays).

Comment: @StephenKitt That explains why I couldn't find a manpage for those functions on man7.org's section 2.

Answer (score 6):

This could be an addition to Stephen Kitt answer, as a comment from `bash` source in file `execute_cmd.c`:

> Execute a simple command that is hopefully defined in a disk file somewhere.
>
> ```
> 1. fork ()
> 2. connect pipes
> 3. look up the command
> 4. do redirections
> 5. execve ()
> 6. If the execve failed, see if the file has executable mode set.
> ```
>
> If so, and it isn't a directory, then execute its contents as a shell script.

Answer (score 0):

It gets executed as a shell script, it is *not* sourced (for instance, variables set in the executed file don't affect outside). Probably vestigial from the misty past, when there was *one* shell and *one* executable format. Not an executable, it must be a shell script.

Comment: You've misunderstood my question. What happens *in detail?* At a minimum, I need to understand what checks for a shebang, is that `exec()` or the shell? I want significantly more internals