# Fastest way to determine if shebang is present

Tags: shell, executable, exec, shebang

If I have a file with

```
#!/usr/bin/env foobar
```

what is the fastest/best way to determine if this file has a hashbang? I hear you can just read the first 2 bytes? How?

Comment: hashbang/shebang are the same thing right?

Comment: the answer is no, I created the hashbang tag for a different question earlier today :)

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/406861/default-executable-for-file-with-potentially-missing-hashbang

Comment: Please don't create tags for made-up terminology.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)

Comment: maybe you can issue an edit to that Wikipedia page

Comment: If we already have a tag for something, use that tag. Maybe suggest a synonym, if you think there’d be value in it.

Comment: I think there are people that know "hashbang" but don't know "shebang"...maybe SE should take care of the synonyms right? Or maybe moderators can define the synonyms? dunno

Comment: not sure which answer to accept

Answer (score 6):

With `zsh`:

```
if LC_ALL=C read -u0 -k2 shebang < file && [ "$shebang" = '#!' ]; then
  echo has shebang
fi
```

Same with `ksh93` or `bash`:

```
if IFS= LC_ALL=C read -rN2 shebang < file && [ "$shebang" = '#!' ]; then
  echo has shebang
fi
```

though `bash` would give false positives for files that start with NULs followed by `#!` and would read *all* the leading NUL bytes so would read a one tebibyte file created with `truncate -s1T file` fully 2 bytes at a time for instance.

So with `bash`, it would be better to use:

```
IFS= LC_ALL=C read -rn2 -d '' shebang
```

That is read *up to* 2 bytes of a NUL-delimited record.

Those don't fork processes nor execute extra commands as the `read`, `[` and `echo` commands are all built-in.

POSIXly, you can do:

```
if IFS= read -r line < file; then
  case $line in
    ("#!"*) echo has shebang
  esac
fi
```

It is stricter in that it also requires a full line. On Linux at least, the newline is not required for a valid shebang though.

So you could do:

```
line=
IFS= read -r line < file
case $line in
  ("#!"*) echo has shebang
esac
```

It's slightly less efficient in that it would potentially read more bytes, with some shells one byte at a time. With our 1TiB sparse file, that would take a lot of time in most shells (and potentially use a lot of memory).

With shells other than `zsh`, it could also give false positives for files that start with NULs followed by `#!`.

With the `yash` shell, it would fail if the shebang contains sequences of bytes that don't form valid characters in the current locale (would even fail (at least with 2.39 and older) if the shebang contained non-ASCII characters in the C locale, even though the C locale is meant to be the one where all characters are single bytes and all the byte values form valid --even if not necessarily defined-- characters)

If you want to find all the files whose content starts with `#!`, you could do:

```
PERLIO=raw find . -type f -size +4c -exec perl -T -ne '
  BEGIN{$/=\2} print "$ARGV\n" if $_ eq "#!"; close ARGV' {} +
```

We're only considering files that are at least 5 bytes large (`#!/x\n` the minimum realistic shebang).

- with `-exec perl... {} +`, we pass as many file paths to `perl` as possible so run as few invocations as possible
- `-T` is to work around [that limitation of `perl -n`](/q/170013) and also means it won't work for files whose name ends in ASCII spacing characters or `|`.
- `PERLIO=raw` causes `perl` to use `read()` system calls directly without any IO buffering layer (affects the printing of file names as well) so it will do reads of size 2.
- `$/ = \2` when the record separator is set as a reference to a number, it causes records to be fixed length ones.
- `close ARGV` skips the rest of the current file after we've read the first record.

Answer (score 4):

You can define your own "magic patterns" in `/etc/magic` and use `file` to test:

```
$ sudo vi /etc/magic
$ cat /etc/magic
# Magic local data for file(1) command.
# Insert here your local magic data. Format is described in magic(5).
0 byte 0x2123 shebang is present
$ cat /tmp/hole2.sh #To prove [1] order of hex [2] 2nd line ignored
!#/bin/bash 
#!/bin/bash
$ cat /tmp/hole.sh 
#!/bin/bash
$ file /tmp/hole2.sh 
/tmp/hole2.sh: ASCII text
$ file /tmp/hole.sh 
/tmp/hole.sh: shebang is present
$ file -b /tmp/hole.sh #omit filename
shebang is present
```

`0x2123` is hex of '#!' in reverse order:

```
$ ascii '#' | head -n1
ASCII 2/3 is decimal 035, hex 23, octal 043, bits 00100011: prints as `#'
$ ascii '!' | head -n1
ASCII 2/1 is decimal 033, hex 21, octal 041, bits 00100001: prints as `!'
```

Optionally you can put:

```
0 string \#\! shebang is present
```

ref: `man 5 magic`,  `man 1 file`,  `man 1posix file`

Answer (score 3):

That should do it:

```
if [ "`head -c 2 infile`" = "#!" ]; then
    echo "Hashbang present"
else
    echo "no Hashbang present"
fi
```

Comment: @don_crissti Indeed. Feel free to edit. And, saga, it isn't obvious to everyone that you'd need to redirect stdin from the file, you should explain that sort of thing.

Comment: @Gilles thanks for pointing out, and corrections.

Comment: unless on OpenBSD, where `head` don't got no `-c` flag. tricky, tricky portability...

Comment: for portability you can use dd instead of head `dd bs=1 c=2 if=infile`

Answer (score 2):

Fast may or may not be best, depending on your feelings on compiling a bunch of C (or maybe some assembly to get all that overhead of C out of the way. and all that tedious error checking, sheesh...)

```
#include <sys/types.h>

#include <err.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <getopt.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sysexits.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int Flag_Quiet;                 /* -q */

void emit_help(void);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int ch;
    char two[2];
    ssize_t amount;

    while ((ch = getopt(argc, argv, "h?q")) != -1) {
        switch (ch) {
        case 'q':
            Flag_Quiet = 1;
            break;
        case 'h':
        case '?':
        default:
            emit_help();
            /* NOTREACHED */
        }
    }
    argc -= optind;
    argv += optind;

    if (argc < 1)
        emit_help();

    if ((ch = open(*argv, O_RDONLY)) == -1)
        err(EX_IOERR, "could not open '%s'", *argv);

    amount = read(ch, two, 2);
    if (amount == -1) {
        err(EX_IOERR, "read failed on '%s'", *argv);
    } else if (amount == 0) {
        err(EX_IOERR, "EOF on read of '%s'", *argv);
    } else if (amount == 2) {
        if (two[0] == '#' && two[1] == '!') {
            amount = 0;
        } else {
            amount = 1;
        }
    } else {
        errx(EX_IOERR, "could not read two bytes from '%s'", *argv);
    }

    if (!Flag_Quiet) {
        printf("%s\n", amount ? "no" : "yes");
    }

    exit(amount);
}

void emit_help(void)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "Usage: hazshebang [-q] file\n");
    exit(EX_USAGE);
}
```

This will require some tweaks if you want a "no" on standard out alongside one of the (many!) `err` exits from the above. Probably better to check the exit status word.

The slower shell way with `head -c 2 file` fails a quick portability test to OpenBSD.

```
$ head -c 2 /etc/passwd
head: unknown option -- c
usage: head [-count | -n count] [file ...]
$
```

Comment: fantastic answer... just compile this and a simple find will fix all files... for me we had ansible-playbook she-bangs in our yaml files, so ```find . -name "*.yml" -exec shebang -q {} \; -exec chmod 0755 {} \;``` worked

Answer (score 1):

use `grep` in a one-liner solution

```
if head -1 file | grep "^#\!" > /dev/null;then echo "true"; fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pwsh` I wanted a portable solution, which wouldn't buffer the entire file (what if the file has no newlines?).

```
$bytes = Get-Content $path -AsByteStream -TotalCount 2
$isShebang = '#!' -eq -join [char[]]$bytes
```

Gets the first two bytes, casts to `char`, joins them to a string to check for equality.

Comment: What shell is this? PowerShell?

Comment: Yeah, [`pwsh`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-linux) is the crossplatform PowerShell binary.