# Various syntax errors when measuring the execution time of a script

Tags: linux, bash, debian, shell, time

Using Cygwin (W10) I've historically used this to measure the execution time within a script:

```
#!/bin/sh

(time {
sleep 1;
})
```

I've now moved to Debian (Windows Subsystem for Linux) and the same script gives this error:

```
Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting ")")
```

I also tried the two suggested scripts here: https://askubuntu.com/a/431184 but both fail:

```
$ foo() {
    sleep 1;
    echo "Hello World"
  }
$ time foo
Hello World
```

and

```
$ foo() {
    sleep 1;
    echo "Hello World"
  }
$ export -f foo
$ echo foo | /usr/bin/time /bin/bash
Hello World
```

with the same error message:

```
Syntax error: "(" unexpected
```

By the way, I've installed `/usr/bin/time`.

Could someone please help?

Thank you

EDIT:
as requested, the script is simply:

```
#!/bin/bash

(time {
sleep 1;
})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script)

Answer (score 5):

`/bin/sh` on Cygwin is likely a symlink to bash, on Debian it's dash. On bash, `time` is a keyword that can act on shell command lines. Dash doesn't have an equivalent, and there `time` is just the external `/usr/bin/time`, and that doesn't act at the same level as the `time` keyword, so it can't be used on command groups.

Use `/bin/bash` for your shebang if you're going to use bashisms like the `time` keyword.

Comment: Thanks for replying.

I just tried

`#!/bin/bash

(time {
sleep 1;
})`
and the result is the same:

Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting ")")
Perhaps it's a more basic syntax error (i.e. I've messed up the brackets)?

Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to show the updated script and how you ran it.

Comment: The updated script works fine enough for me. How are you executing it?

Comment: That's strange. I simply do `sh time.sh` from the Debian WSL window. It then complains that on line 5 `Syntax error: "}" unexpected (expecting ")")` I wonder if this is something specific to WSL.

Comment: Because you're still executing your script with `sh` not bash. Use `bash time.sh`