# Write a Unix shell script to rename a file named common.txt to corporate.txt and check whether it is renamed successfully

Tags: linux, shell-script

```
for f in $* 
do
mv common.txt corporate.txt
done
```

Is it right??

Comment: Welcome to the site. Apart from some syntax errors (which I corrected), your `for` loop will iterate over all command-line arguments, but for everyone execute _the same_ rename command from `common.txt` to `corporate.txt` which must fail already after the first such iteration and is unlikely what you want. If your aim really is to simply rename this one file, you can just execute the `mv` command and inspect the return value, `$?`. If it is `0`, the command was executed successfully; if non-zero, you will know that an error has occured.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only renaming a single file there is no need to loop over all positional parameters, however if you do loop over all positional parameters you should use:

```
for f in "$@"; do
```

`$@` when double quoted will allow you to have parameters that contain spaces without being subject to word splitting and is generally more robust for multiple reasons.

---

On to your script, `mv common.txt corporate.txt` will rename the file as per the parameters (given the `common.txt` file exists within the same directory as the script) but you are performing no check to ensure it was renamed.  Personally I would point to the full path of the file though and perhaps use this is a learning experience for a few slightly unnecessary additions:

- [Parameters/Variables](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_05)
- [command substitution](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_03)
- [dirname](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/dirname.html#tag_20_35)
- [Compound commands](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_04)
- [shell redirection](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_07)

And some necessary additions:

- [hashbang](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/237982)
- [shell test](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/test.html#tag_20_128)

---

Using all this you could create a script like:

```
#!/bin/sh

file=/path/to/common.txt
path=$(dirname "$file")

if mv "$file" "${path}/corporate.txt"; then
    printf '%s\n' "${file}: renamed successfully" >&2
else
    printf '%s\n' "Failed to move: $file" >&2
fi
```

Answer (score -1):

`if mv common.txt corporate.txt; then echo "Success"`

Comment: What about `fi`?