# launching a script: difference between commands `exec` and `bash`?

Tags: bash, shell-script

what is the difference bw:

1. `exec script.sh`
   and
2. `bash script.sh`

assuming script.sh has all the appropriate reading/executing permissions set?

Comment: Related: [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script/87600#87600)

Answer (score 7):

`exec script.sh` *replaces* the current shell with the one defined in the shebang line of `script.sh`, and uses that interpreter to run the rest of the file. This could be anything from `/bin/sh` to `/usr/bin/python`, no matter what the filename extension is. To do this, `script.sh` has to be executable. One of the side effects of this is that when `script.sh` is done the shell also exits. If it is an interactive terminal, the terminal will exit as well.

`bash script.sh` uses a new `bash` shell to interpret `script.sh`, independent of the shebang line. That is, if there is a shebang line it is ignored. `script.sh` does not have to be executable to run it this way.

Comment: `exec script.sh` would also look for it through `PATH`, I think. `bash script.sh` won't

Comment: "the terminal will exit as well" -- depending on how the terminal is configured.

Comment: @glennjackman Every single statement about Bash scripting needs a caveat of "in the vast majority of circumstances". :) The last time I encountered a terminal which didn't exit when the child shell exited was about a decade ago.

Comment: @ilkkachu Bash is the only shell I can test with that performs a `PATH` search if `script.sh` is not found in the current directory (as [documented](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Scripts)). I was actually surprised to see that other shells don't...

Comment: @fra-san, it does? Hngh. Well, Ksh does too, so it's probably inherited from there. Anyway, the point was mostly that as far as I can test, `exec script.sh` looks at `PATH` first, and only there, while `bash script.sh` looks at the current directory first, and then at `PATH`.