# Syntax error near unexpected token `(' when running .sh script

Tags: bash, shell-script, ubuntu

Error is listed below:

```
merge_star.sh: line 19: syntax error near unexpected token `('
merge_star.sh: line 19: `cat <(cat ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/header.txt | sed 's/ /\t/g') ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/tmp.out > ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/STAR_counts.txt'
```

Line in .sh script in question:

```
cat <(cat ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/header.txt | sed 's/ /\t/g') ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/tmp.out > ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/STAR_counts.txt
```

```
#!/bin/bash
# create header file
echo gene_name $(cd ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted && ls *_ReadsPerGene.out.tab | sed s/_ReadsPerGene.out.tab// | sort -u) > ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/header.txt

# Place each sample's STAR gene count file - ReadsPerGene.out.tab in the tmp/ directory 
# The 2nd column (-f2) of ReadsPerGene.out.tab contains the non-stranded counts
for sample in $(cd ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted && ls *_ReadsPerGene.out.tab | sed s/_ReadsPerGene.out.tab// | sort -u)
do 
    echo ${sample}
    cat ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/${sample}_ReadsPerGene.out.tab | tail -n +5 | cut -f2 > ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/${sample}.count
done

# get a list of gene ids (-f1)
tail -n +5 ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/N_1_ReadsPerGene.out.tab | cut -f1 > ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/geneids.txt

# combine all the columns of the count files
paste ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/geneids.txt ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/*.count > ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/tmp.out

# add the header
cat <(cat ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/header.txt | sed 's/ /\t/g') ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/tmp.out > ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/STAR_counts.txt

# remove the tmp folder
rm -rf ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp
```

I am quite new to .sh script coding and I do not see what the error is telling me to fix. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How exactly are you running ths script? the error message suggests POSIX mode

Comment: You might pass the whole script through `shellcheck.net` (online or download). It it quite usual for an earlier line to have an error that only manifests itself later.

Comment: I am running the script by `sh merge_star.sh` in my school's HPC.

Comment: Is the line `cat <(cat ~/asn_project/alignment_sorted/tmp/header.txt | sed 's/ /\t/g')` correct, or did the site remove a '$' between the '<' and the '('? If the '$' is missing in the script itself, that might be your problem or part of it...

Comment: @C.M., that `<( .. )` is process substitution, it makes the output of the command inside available as if in a file. If `header.txt` contains some sort of a header, it would print that (after passing through `sed). `< $( ..)` would use the output of the command inside as a filename to read

Comment: Related: [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script)

Comment: @ilkkachu: Thanks. I knew it was a subshell, but I have not used that form before--I have always saved output to a shellvar (or a tempfile) to feed in elsewhere to avoid unexpected issues. As such, I am used to a subshell being denoted $(....).

Answer (score 5):

In the comments [you say](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/646447/syntax-error-near-unexpected-token-when-running-sh-script#comment1211436_646447) you're running this script with `sh merge_star.sh`. This means you're using `sh` to run the script, but the first line (`#!/bin/bash`) implies it's been written for `bash`. On some systems `sh` and `bash` are the same, but on others they are not; and, when invoked as `sh`, Bash turns off some non-POSIX features, including (for versions up to 5.0) process substitution (`<(...)`). So it's important to use the right shell and the right invocation.

Use `bash merge_star.sh` or *better still*, make the script executable (`chmod a+x merge_star.sh`) and then run it directly (`./merge_star.sh`)

Comment: `sh` on Ubuntu is `dash`.

Comment: Dash would give the error message `merge_star.sh: 20: merge_star.sh: Syntax error: "(" unexpected`

Comment: @ilkkachu You are correct. It is `bash` in POSIX mode. So it's not an up-to-date Ubuntu system they are on, because Ubuntu Focal uses `dash`.

Comment: I did some experimenting between bash and dash, and on my system, dash balks at the <(...) syntax entirely. Not sure if this is any help or not, but I'll let the better shell scriptors make of it what they will.

Comment: Ultimately it doesn't really matter how `sh` is linked. It's the wrong invocation and that's why it's not working

Comment: @Kusalananda, Ubuntu uses Dash _by default_, it can be changed (`dpkg-reconfigure dash`). And the [Ubuntu wiki page on that](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DashAsBinSh) says it's been like that since Ubuntu 6.10, so they'd have to be running something really old to precede that :) But it doesn't matter, for whatever reason they're running the script with `sh`, and that process substitution doesn't work in Bash-called-as-`sh` (in most versions), nor in Dash.