# if-statement with ((...)) string comparison not working in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell-script, string

I have written below script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

STR_1="nfosys"
STR_2="Infosys"

if (( $STR_1 == $STR_2 ))
then
        echo "Strings are equal"
else
        echo "Strings are not equal"
fi
```

Getting Output:

```
root:~/Desktop/user_repo/Demo# bash -x test.sh 
+ STR_1=nfosys
+ STR_2=Infosys
+ ((  nfosys == Infosys  ))
+ echo 'Strings are equal'
Strings are equal
root:~/Desktop/user_repo/Demo#
```

---

Ideally it should print "Strings are not equal" statment but i am unable to understand why it is printing "Strings are equal"

Comment: Edit the question and show how the values of `nfosys` and `Infosys` are being obtained and what they actually are while the script is being run.

Comment: consider "nfosys" and "Infosys" simple string with direct assignment to variable

Comment: `==` inside of `(())` is used for comparing numbers, use `[[` instead for strings.

Comment: See: [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306111/what-is-the-difference-between-the-bash-operators-vs-vs-vs)

Comment: if i add square bracket then getting below message -root@ip-10-0-45-44:~# sh -x test.sh 
+ STR_1=nfosys
+ STR_2=Infosys
+ [[ nfosys == Infosys ]]
test.sh: 6: [[: not found
+ echo Strings are not equal
Strings are not equal
root@ip-10-0-45-44:~#

Comment: @Poonam, run the script with `bash`, not `sh`. Or rather, `chmod +x test.sh` and `./test.sh` so that the hashbang line applies. See: [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script/87600#87600)

Answer (score 7):

`(( .. ))` is an arithmetic construct, and in arithmetic contexts, a string  is taken as the name of a variable, and the value of that variable is used. This happens after `$var` expansions are expanded, so your script looks at variables called `nfosys` and `Infosys`. With both variables unset, both are
taken to be zero, i.e. equal. But:

```
$ str1=foo str2=bar foo=1
$ (( $str1 == $str2 )) && echo true || echo false
false
```

See e.g. [Bash's manual on shell arithmetic](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Arithmetic.html):

> Shell variables are allowed as operands; parameter expansion is performed before the expression is evaluated. Within an expression, shell variables may also be referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax. A shell variable that is null or unset evaluates to 0 when referenced by name without using the parameter expansion syntax.

For string comparison, use

```
[ "$STR_1" = "$STR_2" ]   # in any POSIX shell, or

[[ $STR_1 = "$STR_2" ]]   # in Bash/ksh/zsh
```

The former [needs quotes due to word-splitting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/131766/170373), the latter needs it only on the right-hand side (in bash / ksh) for `$STR_2` not to be taken as a pattern.

Also see: [What is the difference between the Bash operators [[ vs [ vs ( vs ((?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/306111/170373)

Comment: sigh, maybe I'll learn someday.

Comment: I made the same mistake on the code part, if it help :)

Answer (score 1):

Using `[]` instead would give the wanted behavior:

```bsh
STR_1="nfosys"
STR_2="Infosys"

if [ $STR_1 = $STR_2 ]
then
        echo "Strings are equal"
else
        echo "Strings are not equal"
fi
```

Output:

```bsh
+ STR_1=nfosys
+ STR_2=Infosys
+ '[' nfosys = Infosys ']'
+ echo 'Strings are not equal'
Strings are not equal
```

A good rule of thumb is to also quote your variables, just in case they end up being wrongly interpreted or be expanded/split:

```bsh
STR_1="nfosys"
STR_2="Infosys"

if [ "$STR_1" = "$STR_2" ]
then
        echo "Strings are equal"
else
        echo "Strings are not equal"
fi
```

Also, while `[]` is considered POSIX, using `[[]]` if your main target is `bash`, is better.

Editor's note: POSIX only knows single `=`.

Comment: I tried using above but getting below message -test.sh: 6: [[: not found

Comment: if i use single bracket then getting message -test.sh: 6: [: nfosys: unexpected operator

Comment: this is weird. How did you run your script? @Poonam

Comment: Also, thanks for the editor's note ;) I forgot to take this into account

Comment: @Poonam  Pass the script through shellcheck.net. I suspect you have combined parts of several different answers.

Comment: Why show that `[ $STR_1 = $STR_2 ]` (without the quotes) at all? That's very wrong and a command injection vulnerability in shells such as bash. `[ $STR_1 = $STR_2 ]` should be an example of something **not** to do.

Comment: that's true, but I only showed that to emphasize that "this work as it is if you just use [ instead of..." by reusing their own stated example :) And yes, I didn't take into account code injection but I did said quoting was a good rule of thumb and what not @StéphaneChazelas

Answer (score 0):

Thanks All.
i have restarted my session and change to single square bracket -

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

STR_1="nfosys"
STR_2="Infosys"

if [ $STR_1 == $STR_2 ]
then
        echo "Strings are equal"
else
        echo "Strings are not equal"
fi
```

If i execute with sh test.sh then getting error -

```
root@ip:~# sh test.sh 
test.sh: 6: [: nfosys: unexpected operator
Strings are not equal
root@ip:~# bash test.sh 
Strings are not equal
```

If i execute with bash then display correct output without any error

```
root@ip:~# bash test.sh 
Strings are not equal
```

Weird before posting question i had tried both ways - sh/bash and with ()/[].
But after restarting session seems working fine.

---

Editor's refreshed code adhering to POSIX, and some good codex (lower-case variable names, error print to stderr, fixed major `==` issue, etc.):

```sh
#!/bin/sh

str_1=nfosys
str_2=Infosys

if [ "$str_1" = "$str_2" ]; then
    echo "Strings are equal"
else
    echo "Strings are not equal" >&2
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: I hope you won't mind some good advice, feel free to edit it... Cheers, and good luck with Bash/shell in general.

Comment: `[ $STR_1 == $STR_2 ]` is very wrong even with `bash`. It even introduces a command injection vulnerability in bash. That's because of the missing quotes, not the `==` instead of `=` in that case. Try if you dare after `STR_1='-v a[$(reboot)] -o x' STR_2=x` for instance.