# ZSh script to batch process filenames containing spaces and substitute extension

Tags: shell, zsh, batch-jobs

Is there a zsh script that can convert a directory files in one music format and be converted into Ogg opus format.  The *filenames have spaces in their names*.

For example, a directory contains 10 files with *.wma extensions

Files are converted into `*.wav` format using `ffmpeg -i filename.wma filename.wav`

The `*.wav` files are converted to opus using `opusenc --bitrate 160 filename.wav filename.opus`

*Update*: `ffmpeg -i filename.wma -c:a libopus -b:a 128k filename.opus` converts the file with one command

A partially working script will process filenames in current directory from .wma to .wav, even with spaces.  However, the `.wav` extension is added rather than replacing the *.wma file extension

This script was added to a file called `convert` and that file made executable

```
IFS=$'\n'
for x in *.wma ; do
  echo $x
  ffmpeg -i "$x" $x.wav
done
```

Trying to use [Zsh modifiers](https://zsh.sourceforge.io/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Modifiers) to substitute the filename extension with: `${x:e}".wav` (and after a suggestion by ilkkachu I also tried `${x:r}".wav`)

```
IFS=$'\n'
for x in *.wma ; do
  ffmpeg -i "$x" "${x:e}".wav
done
```

Calling this from a file called `convert`, the following error is returned

```
./convert: 3: Bad substitution
```

The same error happens with

```
IFS=$'\n'
for x in *.wma ; do
  ffmpeg -i "$x" "${x:r}".wav
done
```

I assume the syntax is not quite write or modifiers do not work when filenames have spaces. Or I still have a lot to learn about zsh :)

Is there a correct way to substitute a filename extension in Zsh (when file names contain spaces)

Thank you.

Comment: can you [edit] the question to show the exact error you get?

Comment: Why not simply use a boring old POSIX `"${x%.*}.wav"`?

Comment: Then the minor things here are that you probably meant `${x:r}` and that in zsh just expanding `$1` wouldn't by default take it as a glob. But you edited that now.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but `${x.r}` also has the same error, which I am guessing is because I wrap that in a string as the file names contain spaces `"${x.r}"`.  Perhaps I need to generate the output filename separately...

Comment: Does your script start with a line like `#!/usr/bin/zsh`? If not, it will be interpreted by `sh`, not `zsh`. In this case, the shell will complain about zsh-only syntax.

Comment: Again: Does `"${x%.*}.wav"` work?

Comment: I wonder how you run the script. `Bad substitution` with the B capitalized looks like an error from Dash, Debian/Ubuntu's `/bin/sh`. Zsh would give `bad substitution` all in lowercase (and Bash would print the expansion in the error message too, and Busybox would also say "syntax error")

Comment: see e.g. [Does the shebang determine the shell which runs the script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/87560/170373)

Comment: Specifying `#!/usr/bin/zsh` was the part that was missing, thanks Bodo.  Yes, Philippos, the posix approach works too.  Thanks all.

Comment: and [Which shell interpreter runs a script with no shebang?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/373223/170373)

Answer (score 2):

While your problem was that you had the script interpreted by `sh` instead of `zsh`, in `zsh`, you could use `zmv` here:

```
#! /bin/zsh -
autoload zmv
zmv -P ffmpeg -o -i './(*).wma' './$1.wav'
```

`zmv` normally does batch renaming, but can also do batch copying / linking or batch-anything if given the name of the command to do the *anything*.

You benefit from the few safeguards that it performs before doing anything (check that the destination files don't exist or that not two source files map to the same target).

Note also the `./` prefix to avoid problems with filenames starting with `-` or in general to work around the unsafe CLI of `ffmpeg`.

In any case the `IFS=$'\n'` in your code serves no purpose as you're not using IFS word splitting (only done upon command substitution and `$=param` in zsh), nor using things like `"$array[*]"` to join elements of an array with the first element of `$IFS` and anyway in `zsh`, you'd rather use the `s[sep]` / `f` / `0` parameter expansion flags to split or `j[sep]` to join rather than changing `$IFS` globally. Also beware that newline is as valid a character as any in a file name.

Comment: zmv looks great.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To use Zsh modifiers (and other zsh specific syntax) a script added to a file should start by defining it is a zsh script

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh
```

Optionally, check the location of zsh first by using the `which zsh` if unsure your OS uses this location

> Adding this line may also add specific zsh syntax highlighting when opening the file in an editor

The shell variable IFS (Internal Field Separator) determines how word boundaries are recognised when splitting a sequence of character strings, such as a directory listing.

Setting IFS to `$'\n'` in zsh allows use of filenames that contain spaces

```
IFS=$'\n'
```

Using a `for` loop will iterate through all the files in the current directory, using wildcards - `*.wma` for that file extension in the current directory or `**/*.wma` for current and sub-directories

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

IFS=$'\n'
for x in *.wma ; do
  ffmpeg -i "$x" "${x:r}".wav
done
```

ffmpeg can convert to opus files using the `libopus` audio codec, so do not need to be converted to a format that opusenc tool supports.

```
ffmpeg -i original-file.wma -b:a 128k -c:a libopus ouptut-file.opus
```

where `-b:a` is the audio bitrate and `-c:a` is the audio codec

Putting that all together the final script is:

```
#!/usr/bin/zsh

IFS=$'\n'
for x in *.wma ; do
  ffmpeg -i "$x" -b:a 128k -c:a libopus "${x:r}".opus
done
```

Comment: I don't think you really need `IFS=$'\n'` there, as you're not using word splitting for anything.