# How to declare each outputs if there are multiple output in a single query in shell script?

Tags: shell-script, shell, checksum

I want to write a condition if the output matches by executing the below command.

```
diff -is <(echo 'curl https://get.gravitational.com/teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz.sha256') \
         <(shasum -a 256 teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz)
```

The output of the above command come as

```
< 15c7fabe609513fdba95ff68ccc59f29502f32f4d20c163bd9ff47770b554d15 teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz
> 15c7fabe609513fdba95ff68ccc59f29502f32f4d20c163bd9ff47770b554d15  teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz
```

in this scenario since the checksum matches, how to declare each output to add in a condition.
Eg: if output a==output b, checksum matches.
Great if anyone can help.

Thank you for your answers. I have tried with the below answers and able to execute as per my requirement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the URL and filename substituted, the command you're actually running is this:

```
diff -is <(echo `curl "$url"`)  <(shasum -a 256 "$file")
                ^           ^
```

Note that's backticks in `` echo `curl...` `` , not single quotes as in your post(*). Passing the output of `curl` through that unquoted command substitution applies word splitting, giving two distinct arguments to `echo`, which then joins them with a single space. In effect, changing the double space in the file to a single one.

(* with single quotes, it'd output `curl https://...`, not run it as a command)

See:

- [Why does my shell script choke on whitespace or other special characters?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131766/why-does-my-shell-script-choke-on-whitespace-or-other-special-characters)
- [When is double-quoting necessary?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/68694/when-is-double-quoting-necessary)
- http://mywiki.wooledge.org/WordSplitting

That's also the reason `diff` gives any output at all: the lines differ in only that one space.

If you drop the useless command substitution and run

```
diff -is <(curl "$url")  <(shasum -a 256 "$file")
```

instead, it should recognize the files as identical, and with `-s`, tell you that. Then, you could just use the exit status of `diff` directly without caring about the printed output:

```
if diff -iq <(curl "$url")  <(shasum -a 256 "$file") > /dev/null; then
    echo "hashes are the same"
else
    echo "hashes differ"
fi
```

Though you don't need `diff` there except for the case-ignoring function, but I don't think that's necessary. You could store the outputs in shell variables and compare them:

```
their=$(curl "$url")
mine=$(shasum -a 256 "$file")
if [[ "$their" == "$mine" ]]; then
    echo "hashes match"
else
    echo "hashes do not match"
fi
```

Or, if you want to compare just the initial part with the hash:

```
their=$(curl "$url")
their=${their%% *}
mine=$(shasum -a 256 "$file")
mine=${mine%% *}
if [[ "$their" == "$mine" ]]; then
    ...
```

Or even something like

```
read -r hash1 filename1 < <(curl "$url")
etc.
```

to read both fields from the output to separate variables.

Comment: Thanks you. I'm able to execute directly in terminal. But while executing, i'm getting the below error.
:syntax error near unexpected token `('
/line 7: `if diff -iq <(curl "https://get.gravitational.com/teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz.sha256")  <(shasum -a 256 "teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz") > /dev/null; then'. 
if diff -iq <(curl "https://get.gravitational.com/teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz.sha256")  <(shasum -a 256 "teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz") > /dev/null; then
    echo "hashes are the same"
else
    echo "hashes differ"
fi

Comment: @user123codebit, run the script with `bash`, not `sh`. See: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/87560/does-the-shebang-determine-the-shell-which-runs-the-script

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `diff`-ing the `*.sha256` and the output of `shasum`, I would let shasum use its own built-in "check" option (`shasum -c`) for this.

In action:

```
$ echo "This is a file" > file1
$ echo "This is another file" > file2
$ shasum -a 256 file* | tee files.sha256
0b7d91193b9c0f5cc01d40332a10cf1ed338a41640bd7f045f1087628c1d7a9b  file1
0290013ed1662eda102bee144a282ffe03d226b4dd9134c251c6b3be6d69d6ec  file2


$ shasum -c files.sha256
file1: OK
file2: OK
$ echo $?
0

$ echo "damaged file" > file1

$ shasum -c files.sha256
file1: FAILED
file2: OK
shasum: WARNING: 1 computed checksum did NOT match
$ echo $?
1
```

If you are script this, then the exit-code from shasum -c can tell you if the verification was successful.

So in your case, I would:

```
wget https://get.gravitational.com/teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz.sha256
shasum -c teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz.sha256
rm teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz.sha256
```

or

```
shasum -c <(curl https://get.gravitational.com/teleport-v9.3.4-linux-amd64-bin.tar.gz.sha256)
```